# Why does #if debug not work on the server

Tags: .net, web-services

I have

```
 #if debug then
 #end if
```

statements inside a webservice which outputs event viewer logs.  This works ok when testing locally. If I build a debug version and then copy the files across to the live server and re-cycle the app pool of the webservice, I don't see these logs in the event viewer.  Is there any reason why this isn't working?

Comment: Is debug enabled on the server, especially in the web.config?

Comment: Does the web application user account (as defined in the linked application pool) have permissions to write to the event log?

Comment: @SteveB - With a preprocessor directive like the above, the code will be compiled and run, regardless of IIS/web.config settings.

Comment: It depends if the web service is precompiled or not, isn't it? and if jaffa has put the code inline in an .Asmx file, this will be compiled by IIS and thus, using the debug parameter

Comment: Web service is precompiled beforehand.  In web.config, debug = TRUE is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<compilation debug="true" />`does *not* define the DEBUG preprocessor flag. You would need to modify the system.codedom configuration to do that. The default Visual Studio template comes with predefined flags (Project Settings > Build, "Define DEBUG constant" and "Define TRACE constant") which is why they work in project you compile within Visual Studio.

Use [HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your event log source first. This requires admin privileges.
I ofen use an simple console app (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667248/windows-event-log-how-to-register-an-event-source)) to register event log sources that I use within web apps and services.